# Spring 4 - Cannot load configuration class

Tags: java, spring

When i try to use the config class (AppConfig) i get the following error

Cannot load configuration class AppConfig

Spring version is 4.0.1 , thanks you.

Code:

```
   ApplicationContext ctx =
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOperation =
            (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
```

Pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score -1):

What is `AppConfig`? I assume that it is a configuration class you created.
For custom configuration classes, Spring make use of an annotation `@Configuration`.
Add above your name class the annotation and run again your app.
Please try to post it and add more details in your question.

Comment: This is a comment (with some good info), not an answer